# Why is my postfix evalutation function not working?

Tags: python, postfix-notation

This is what I have so far, this is a continutation of some pythoncode my classmate wrote and we keep getting lots of errors.

I think the errors lie somewhere in the if and for loop but I am fairly new to coding so any help would be appriciated.

```
def postfix(expr_str: str) -> float:
    op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    mystack = []
    ch = expr_str.split()
    
    if ch not in op:
        mystack.append(ch)
    for ch in expr_str:
        if ch.isdigit():
            mystack.append(ch)
        else:
            op_2 = mystack.pop() # remove mst recent operand from stack first
            op_1 = mystack.pop() # remove first operand from the stack after
            if ch == '+':
                mystack.append(op_1 + op_2)
            elif ch == '-':
                mystack.append(op_1 - op_2)
            elif ch == '/':
                mystack.append(op_1 - op_2)
            elif ch == '*':
                mystack.append(op_1 / op_2)
            mystack.append(mystack)
    return (''.join(mystack))
```

I already tried to run this through coding rooms but there were many errors.

Comment: Main problem seems to be that you didn't convert the strings of digits to  numbers before doing arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few problems in your code:

- `if ch not in op` makes no sense, because `ch` is at that moment a list of strings -- which you got from `expr_str.split()`. This `if` block should not be there, nor the assignment to `ch`. And by consequence the variable `op` is also not used anymore. Just remove that code.
- `for ch in expr_str:` will read individual characters from the input string. This would split "123" into "1", "2", and "3". Instead, here it would be a good moment to do `for ch in expr_str.split()`, assuming that the given expression is space separated, like for instance "1 2 3 * +".
- `mystack.append(op_1 + op_2)` assumes that `op_1` and `op_2` are numeric, but your code only puts strings on the stack, not numbers. So change `mystack.append(ch)` (the one after the `isdigit` test) to `mystack.append(int(ch))`
- You haven't applied multiplication and division where you're supposed to do that.
- `mystack.append(mystack)` makes no sense: it would duplicate the contents of the stack. This statement should be removed.
- After the above corrections, `''.join(mystack)` will not work, because now the stack has numbers, not strings. In fact, if the input expression was semantically correct, there should be *exactly* one number on the stack, so you should actually do `return stack[0]` or `return stack[-1]`

With the above fixes your code would look like this:

```
def postfix(expr_str) -> float:
    mystack = []
    for ch in expr_str.split():
        if ch.isdigit():
            mystack.append(int(ch))
        else:
            op_2 = mystack.pop()
            op_1 = mystack.pop()
            if ch == '+':
                mystack.append(op_1 + op_2)
            elif ch == '-':
                mystack.append(op_1 - op_2)
            elif ch == '/':
                mystack.append(op_1 / op_2)
            elif ch == '*':
                mystack.append(op_1 * op_2)
    return (mystack[0])
```

You could further improve by checking for errors in the input string, like an invalid operator (add an `else` after the last `elif`), or too few operands (that happens when the list is empty when you are about to `pop`), or too many operands (this happens when at the end the stack has more than one number), or the input is empty,... etc.

Example run:

```
print(postfix("1 2 3 * +"))  # 7
```

Comment: Any feedback? Did this resolve your issue?